# Negative Mean Square Error

Tags: statistics, self-learning, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics, mean-square-error

For simple random sampling,

I have calculated somemean square errors for ratio-type estimators such as Isaki estimator, and Prasad Singh estimator.

But, Mean Square Errors i obtained are negative. Does MSE eqaul to a negative value? I there a mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake. MSE can never be negative, because its an expected value of a non-negative random variable (and thus is non-negative itself).

Comment: Well, Do you know Isaki  estimator and Prasad singh 1&2 estimators?

Comment: No. But, MSE is never negative in any definition.

Comment: well, i have one more question to you. i find negative value of MSE for three different type of estimators while doing my homework. but there is no mistake. i guess, the problem result from the formula of MSE given by my instructor. because no one find a positive value for these estimators in the class. In my homework, i will say that "for my data set, these three estimators cannot be used because of negative value of MSE." Is this sentence is appropriate?

Comment: Talk to your instructor -- MSE is never negative in any definition, so get them to fix the definition.

Comment: dear @Batman bias of an estimator can be a negative? Is there a problem again?

Comment: Bias can be positive or negative. You can see a book like elements of statistical learning or any intro to statistics for details on bias-variance tradeoffs.

Comment: okay there is no problem for being negative bias. i will read it. thank you:)) dear @Batman